# jquery is(" :focus" ) not working in safari. any solution for this IF($(this).parents('form').find('.back').is( ":focus" ) )

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, safari, focus

I am using jQuery and I have this code in my common.js file.

This code fires the `submit` or `next` button when the user presses enter anywhere on the page.

I am using two different CSS classes for the `Cancel` and `Submit` buttons, which are `.btn` classes and all the `Next` buttons use the `.back` class.

This code works fine for Internet Explorer, FireFox, and Chrome. Only Safari is giving me a hard time. When the user focuses on `Cancel` and then presses `Enter` it submits the form instead of canceling it.

Does anyone have a solution for this? I have tried a number of things but nothing works.

If you have a Safari-specific solution or a solution that works for all browsers please let me know because now I am unable to change my JSP code.

Thank you in advance.

```
// Common.js

$("form *").live('keypress', function (e) {
    if ($(this).parents('form').find('button[type=submit].btn, input
type=submit].btn').length <= 0) {
        return true;
    }
    if ($(this).parents('form').find('textarea').is(":focus")) {
        alert(' Function Call ');
        return true;
    } * * *
    if ($(this).parents('form').find('.back').is(":focus")) {
        return true;
    } * * *
    if ((e.which && e.which == 13) || (e.keyCode && e.keyCode == 13)) {
        $(this).parents('form').find('button[type=submit].btn, input
[type=submit].btn').click();
        return false;
    }
});

// test.jsp
<div class="back-link">  
    <div class="back-btn-wrap">              
        <html:cancel styleClass="back" onclick="bCancel=true">cancel</html:cancel>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-wrap">        
        <html:submit styleClass="btn" property="submitNext"> Submit / Next</html:submit>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsbeautifier.org/, go!

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? :focus does appear to be implemented into the core since 1.6, it just isn't in the new api.

Comment: I've been using `$(elm).is(':focus')` for quite sometime and my main browser, Safari never had any issues with that. In your scenario I would make sure I'm targeting the right element(s) in my code. Also, you might want to switch to the `.on()` handler since `.live()` is deprecated as of some older version of jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to figure out which element has focus, you can use...

```
$(document.activeElement)
```

If you aren't sure if the version will be 1.6 or lower, you can add the `:focus` selector if it is missing...

```
(function ( $ ) {
    var filters = $.expr[":"];
    if ( !filters.focus ) { 
        filters.focus = function( elem ) {
           return elem === document.activeElement && ( elem.type || elem.href );
        };
    }
})( jQuery );
```